# Is there a way to create a sheet report for authentication handled by firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, report

I couldn't find this information anywhere, so I'm sorry if this was already answered.

I'm developing an educational game and I'm using the Google Firebase to handle the authentication. I want a sheet report for whom logged on the game and when. I know that this information is available in the Authentication Menu of the https://console.firebase.google.com. What I need to know is if there is a way to get this report in sheet(csv) format. Also, if the game is published/posted on site, would the Google Analytics create this report for me?

Thanks for the help!

PS.: the game still is just a executable prototype that I run on my machine, so the Google Analytics still isn't running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to retrieve information about who signed in to your project using Firebase Authentication. If you want something like that, you could build it yourself on top of it, although the most common approach is to log events to Analytics with a suitable [user ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid).

Comment: Glad to know! Thank you!